# Any chapter length study on the phenomenology of my reflection in a mirror?

Tags: phenomenology, perception

Is there any chapter length study on the phenomenology of my reflection in a mirror? I'm just looking for a philosophical description of what's happening there, it has nothing to do with my (highly limited) understanding of Husserl's project.

---

I suppose I like the idea that, if you take it as a paradigm, then my conception of myself from the outside is identical to the inside of me, my visual impressions.

Comment: Lacan's writing on the "mirror stage" might be relevant... Can you specify a little more closely what you're looking for? (What resources have you found so far?)

Comment: @JosephWeissman i don't know of any resources. i googled "phenomenology of reflection" and it was about bretano. "phenomenology of mirrors" only got some cute facebook group. if i were to go with lacan, how could i go about reading it as philosophy rather than psychoanalysis?

Comment: The distinction is really not quite so clear---plenty of philosophers have used psychoanalysis (eg Frankfurt school) fairly directly. Read it like you would any philosophical text.

Comment: @Canyon am skeptical it will have the right answers, but will likely try

Comment: to the best of my ability i mean